# Knockout JS 2.0.0 library breaks in IE 8

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hey is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

I have tried not using the KO debug version and I get the same error on the same line. If I upgrade to 2.2.1 my page breaks. I get NaN in date fields and all my jquery validation fields are red.

I found this problem because my ko if tags, <-- ko if: expression --> were not working in IE 8 so I changed the if to be 'if' and then I got this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you performing width or height bindings? Anything along these lines: `<li class="graham" data-bind="style: { height: someFunction() }">` ???

Comment: I have some attr bindings

Comment: I removed the attr bindings and I still get the same error

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1, jquery ui 1.8.9, ko js 2.0.0 jquery validate

Comment: Could you post a fiddle illustrating your problem in IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upgrade to jquery 1.9 and knockout 2.2.1. To fix my page text from being red, I had to make sure all my  tags were like this:  instead of . I also ran my html with the w3 validators and fixed some other minimal issues.